# Javascript Function for radio button other option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a `radio` buttons for selection and there is "other" button when clicked by user it'll open `text-box` so that user can manually specify some text inside it.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="">Web</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="">Mobile Apps</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="other">Other</label>
<input typt="text" placeholder="Specify here" id="other-text">
```

And javascript

```
$(".option").change(function () {
//check if the selected option is others
if (this.value === "other") {
    //toggle textbox visibility
    $("#other-text").toggle();
}
});
```

This is what i've tried but somehow it's not working.
I'm newbie to `javascript` so please help me.

Thanks in advance.

If possible can you also tell me how to put `jsfiddle/codepen` links?

Comment: Just a pointer `.selector` means selector is a css class and not attribute. For name you should use `[name='value']` or better `input[name='value']`. [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/n6vtfpum/). Also, if you use `.toggle` and click on `other` twice, element will hide again. `.hide/.show` would suit your requirement more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```js
$(".js-option").click(function () {
//check if the selected option is others
    if ($(this).val() == "other") {
        $("#other-text").show();
    }else{
        $("#other-text").hide();
    }
});
```

```css
#other-text{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="option" class="js-option" value="">Web</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="option" class="js-option" value="">Mobile Apps</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="option" class="js-option" value="other">Other</label>
<input typt="text" placeholder="Specify here" id="other-text">
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for the help

Comment: @KishanPatel Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("[name='option']").change(function () {
    //check if the selected option is others
    if (this.value === "other") {
        //toggle textbox visibility
        $("#other-text").show();
    } else {
        //toggle textbox visibility
        $("#other-text").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a class selector `$(".option")`. But you have not assigned any class to it. Unless you assign a class you have to use jquery input name selector to target the element

```
$( "input[name='option']" ).change(function(){
// $(".option").change(function () {  // if using class
if (this.value === "other") {
    $("#other-text").show();
}
else{
 $("#other-text").hide();
}
});
```

Check this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7dLpp5vf/)

Comment: Thanks..But can you please tell me how you put that jsfiddle link??

Answer (score 0):

Set other text box display none first ! Then display text when click radio button `other` ...

```
<input typt="text" placeholder="Specify here" id="other-text" style="display:none">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(":radio").change(function () {
        //check if the selected option is others
        $("#other-text").hide();
        if (this.value === "other") { 
              $("#other-text").show();
        }
});
</script>
```